# Как поменять позицию text element в pysimplegui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Я не могу найти как поменять положение текстового элемента в библиотеке pysimplegui. Кто-нибудь знает как?

Comment: относительно чего нужно изменить положение?

Comment: мне нужно было изменить положение элемента в окне. Но я похоже уже нашёл решение этой проблеммы я буду использовать pad, но если есть другой способ то я буду рад услышать